# Using a loop to fill excel file instead of hard coding cell co-ordinates

Tags: phpexcel

I have this code listing which exports data to an excel file shown [here](http://www.alphybay.com/nqcl/assay_pic.png)!, I would like to use a loop that does the same thing instead of hard coding it, suggestions!

```
       $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("workbooks/" . $labref . "/" . $labref . ".xlsx");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('I3', $heading)
                ->setCellValue('I5', 'Standard Preparation For Assay')
                ->setCellValue('B7', 'Weight')
                    …………

                //Assay Standard Preparation desired  
                ->setCellValue('A8', 'Desired Weight')
                ->setCellValue('B8', $weight)
                ->setCellValue('C8', $vf1)
                   …………………..

                //Other values used
                ->setCellValue('D22', 'Label Claim')
                ->setCellValue('D23', 'Tabs or Caps Average')
                     ……..
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($heading);
        $dir = "workbooks";
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save("workbooks/" . $labref . "/" . $labref . ".xlsx");

        } 
    }
```

Comment: If you want to loop rows, then use a row number counter and set cell addresses as 'D'.$rowCounter

Comment: show an example so i get a clear example

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$data = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM form'); //Im using redbean 
$url = // Your url from the root dir -> the folder you wanna save to


$header = array();
$index = 0;
foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
  $header[$index] = $key;
  $index += 1;
}

try {
  $sheet = new PHPExcel();
  $sheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Username')
                          ->setLastModifiedBy('Username')
                          ->setTitle('Title');
  $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(
          PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
  $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
          PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
  $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(12);

  $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();



  $colHeaders = $header;
  $col = 'B';
  $rownum = 2;

  foreach ($colHeaders as $h) {
    $activeSheet->setCellValue($col . $rownum, $h);
    $activeSheet->getStyle($col . $rownum)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $activeSheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
    $col++;
  }

  foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $col = 'B';
    $rownum++;
    if ($k != count($data)) {
      foreach ($v as $value) {
          $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rownum, $value);
      }
    } else {
      foreach ($v as $value) {
        $rownum++;
        $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rownum, $value);
      }
    }
  }

  $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');

  // The URL needs to be a absolute path from the root folder to the save folder
  // time() makes sure that the file has a uniq name and allso makes it easy to 
  // see the leatest verson of it.
  $saveObj = $url . time() . '';
  $writer->save($saveObj);
  exit();



} catch (Exception $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();
  // print("<pre>".print_r($error,true)."</pre>");
}
print("<pre>".print_r($error,true)."</pre>");
exit();
```